# hidden header drop down on click

Tags: javascript, css

For a site I am working on I'd quite like to use a similar drop down effect as here http://shop.jack-hughes.com/ when you click info a hidden div drops down.

I can't work out if it uses only CSS3 or Javascript/CSS can anyone point me in the right direction or tell me the name of the effect; pretty simple I guess but for the life of me can't find another example.

Comment: what 'drop down' effect. His this just a fishing link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

combination of CCS3 and js

Here is what is used in the website you refer

**js**:

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function () {
    Event.observe('info', 'click', function () {
        $('aside').toggleClassName('open');
    });
});
```

`Event.observe` is from the  **prototype** framework - http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/Event/observe/

The equivalent in jQuery(http://jquery.com/) for instance would be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.info').click(function () {
        $('aside').toggleClass('open');
    })
});
```

**css**:

```
aside.open {
    height: 21.25em;
}

aside {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #3f4642;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

The HTML element is `<aside>....</aside>` but it's no difference if you choose div.

Comment: Thank you for making it a lot clearer! I will go and experiment!

Answer (score 0):

They have a small piece of Javascript that does this that can be easily done on any website. Basically you need a hidden div at the top of your page, and upon clicking a link you simply show the div.

The code that they used was:

```
Event.observe('info', 'click', function(){
    $('aside').toggleClassName('open');
});
```

But if you take a look at [jquery](http://jquery.com/) then you will see that manipulation of elements is quite easy to do.

One thing that they do use in addition is a CSS3 transition in their `open` class:

```
.aside {
     transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s
}
```

This is what is causing the smooth transition effect. So you can use either jQuery or the CSS3 transition, both give the same effect. I would say that the CSS3 transition is nicer, but then again you will be alienating certain browsers if they do not support transitions.

Comment: Thank you for making it a lot clearer! I will go and experiment!

Answer (score 0):

Probably using jQuery. Something like:

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Deif discovered they're also using CSS transition

```
transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
```

and also make use of the "::selection" pseudo class for their "aside" class, see [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3a%3aselection)